# Can i use the Newton-Raphson method of scipy.optimize with a multiple variable system?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I wanted to do the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) with scipy with a multivariable system. So, i followed this [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html#scipy.optimize.newton). And here is an example code where i tried to solved my problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton


def f(x):
    F = [0, 0]
    F[0] = 5 * x[0] + 7 * x[1] - 6
    F[1] = 10 * x[0] - 3 * x[1] - 46

    return F


def jacobian(x):
    F = np.zeros((2, 2))
    F[0, 0] = 5
    F[0, 1] = 7
    F[1, 0] = 10
    F[1, 1] = -3

    return F


q = [10, -10]
result = newton(f, q, fprime=jacobian, maxiter=10000, full_output=1)
print(result)
```

When i run this program without the 'fprime' parameter (in the newton function), i get the correct answer:

> result(root=array([ 3.99999999, -2.00000004]), converged=array([ True,  True]), zero_der=array([False, False]))

But this is the secant method and i need the Newton method for a more complex problem. So when i run the code with the parameter 'fprime' i get the following error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Seeing this error i tried several solutions, like changing the matrix F from the jacobian function to a normal list:

```
def jacobian(x):
    F = [0,0,0,0]
    F[0] = 5
    F[1] = 7
    F[2] = 10
    F[3] = -3

    return F
```

Or changing all the variable to numpy arrays, but i keep getting similar errors with index.

I want know if it is posible to do this system of equations with this scipy function and if not, i would like other alternatives with python.

Comment: Im not sure why this doesnt work. If you replace your jacobian function with `scipy.optimize.approx_fprime(x, f)` you get the same jacobian as your code.

Comment: Show the full error message - so you, and we, know exactly which indexing is wrong.

Comment: This may be the wrong method for coupled variables like this.  It's not intended for a coupled system of variables.  Rather it's a single variable equation, that can be evaluated with multiple starting points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback is

```
  Cell In[46], line 26
    result = newton(f, q, fprime=jacobian, maxiter=10000, full_output=1)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_zeros_py.py:277 in newton
    return _array_newton(func, x0, fprime, args, tol, maxiter, fprime2,

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_zeros_py.py:401 in _array_newton
    dp = fval[nz_der] / fder[nz_der]

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Changing the `ipython` %xmode` to verbose,  the error line, with context and variables is:

```
File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_zeros_py.py:401, in _array_newton(func=<function f>, x0=[10, -10], fprime=<function jacobian>, args=(), tol=1.48e-08, maxiter=10000, fprime2=None, full_output=1)
    399     break
    400 # Newton step
    400 # Newton step
--> 401 dp = fval[nz_der] / fder[nz_der]
        nz_der = array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])
        fval = array([-26,  84])
        fder = array([[ 5.,  7.],
       [10., -3.]])
```

I think `fval` is the 1d array produced by `f(q)`.  `fder` is the 2d array produced by `jacobian`, and `nz_der` looks like a matching shape boolean.

You/we need to review the `newton` docs to see what shape of a result the `fprime` must be.

The docs aren't specific about what `fprime` must return, but from that error, and the examples like `fprime=lambda x: 3 * x**2)`, it must be a 1d array like `f(q)`, the same shape as in guess `q`.  You are trying to provide the 2d dz/dx.

Using `np.array([5,7,10,-3])` has indexing problem at the same place, only with a (4,) boolean instead of the (2,2).

From your linked docs:

> If x0 is a sequence with more than one item, newton returns an array: the zeros of the function from each (scalar) starting point in x0. In this case, func must be vectorized to return a sequence or array of the same shape as its first argument. If fprime (fprime2) is given, then its return must also have the same shape: each element is the first (second) derivative of func with respect to its only variable evaluated at each element of its first argument.

Comment: I didnt see it. The same documentation that i linked say in the next line: "newton is for finding roots of a scalar-valued functions of a single variable. For problems involving several variables, see root.". Thank you @hpaulj for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Newton's method for a specific nonlinear system of equations, use fsolve.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# Defining the system of equations
def f(r):
    x, y = r
    equation1 = 5 * x + 7 * y - 6
    equation2 = 10 * x - 3 * y - 46
    return np.array([equation1, equation2])

# Jacobian derivative
def jacobian(r):
    x, y = r
    d_equation1_dx = 5
    d_equation1_dy = 7
    d_equation2_dx = 10
    d_equation2_dy = -3
    return np.array([[d_equation1_dx, d_equation1_dy], [d_equation2_dx, d_equation2_dy]])

# Kickstart to the solution
r0 = np.array([0.0, 0.0])

# Using fsolve with Jacobian
solution = fsolve(func=f, x0=r0, fprime=jacobian, full_output=False, xtol=1.49012e-08)

print(f'solution of the system of equations: {solution}')
print(f'f({solution}): {f(solution)}')
```

From what I've read in the documentation, as well as from the examples provided by the developers, it seems to me that scipy.optimize.newton is applicable to single-variable problems. Here, I made the switch to fsolve (scipy.optimize.fsolve), there's another option in scipy called scipy.optimize.root. The code above is just a reformulation of yours.